# Why can I NOT export a Godot 3 project to HTML5?

Tags: html, godot

If I export a Godot 3 project to HTML and I run my index.html on local server, I get the below error. Any ideas why? If I test other Godot 3 projects on the web I get stuck too. I tried to install emscripten in Ubuntu, but no success. I tried old Godot 2 projects in HTML on the web and they worked in 2D. However, I want to export my Godot 3 projects and I have had no success in either a 2D or a 3D project.

```
Output: Clear
167: 
168: #endif
169: 
170: uniform bool z_flip;
171: 
172: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_PANORAMA
173: 
174: vec4 texturePanorama(vec3 normal,sampler2D pano ) {
175: 
176:    vec2 st = vec2(
177:        atan(normal.x, normal.z),
178:        acos(normal.y)
179:    );
180: 
181:    if(st.x < 0.0)
182:        st.x += M_PI*2.0;
183: 
184:    st/=vec2(M_PI*2.0,M_PI);
185: 
186:    return textureLod(pano,st,0.0);
187: 
188: }
189: 
190: #endif
191: 
192: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_DUAL_PARABOLOID_ARRAY
193: 
194: 
195: vec4 textureDualParaboloidArray(vec3 normal) {
196: 
197:    vec3 norm = normalize(normal);
198:    norm.xy/=1.0+abs(norm.z);
199:    norm.xy=norm.xy * vec2(0.5,0.25) + vec2(0.5,0.25);
200:    if (norm.z<0.0) {
201:        norm.y=0.5-norm.y+0.5;
202:    }
203:    return textureLod(source_dual_paraboloid_array, vec3(norm.xy, float(source_array_index) ), 0.0);
204: 
205: }
206: 
207: #endif
208: 
209: void main() {
210: 
211: #ifdef USE_DUAL_PARABOLOID
212: 
213:    vec3 N = vec3( uv_interp * 2.0 - 1.0, 0.0 );
214:    N.z = 0.5 - 0.5*((N.x * N.x) + (N.y * N.y));
215:    N = normalize(N);
216: 
217:    if (z_flip) {
218:        N.y=-N.y; //y is flipped to improve blending between both sides
219:        N.z=-N.z;
220:    }
221: 
222: 
223: #else
224:    vec2 uv         = (uv_interp * 2.0) - 1.0;
225:    vec3 N          = texelCoordToVec(uv, face_id);
226: #endif
227:    //vec4 color = color_interp;
228: 
229: #ifdef USE_DIRECT_WRITE
230: 
231: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_PANORAMA
232: 
233:    frag_color=vec4(texturePanorama(N,source_panorama).rgb,1.0);
234: #endif
235: 
236: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_DUAL_PARABOLOID_ARRAY
237: 
238:    frag_color=vec4(textureDualParaboloidArray(N).rgb,1.0);
239: #endif
240: 
241: #if !defined(USE_SOURCE_DUAL_PARABOLOID_ARRAY) && !defined(USE_SOURCE_PANORAMA)
242: 
243:    N.y=-N.y;
244:    frag_color=vec4(texture(N,source_cube).rgb,1.0);
245: #endif
246: 
247: 
248: 
249: 
250: #else
251: 
252:    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
253: 
254:    for(uint sampleNum = 0u; sampleNum < SAMPLE_COUNT; sampleNum++) {
255:        vec2 xi = Hammersley(sampleNum, SAMPLE_COUNT);
256: 
257:        vec3 H  = ImportanceSampleGGX( xi, roughness, N );
258:        vec3 V  = N;
259:        vec3 L  = normalize(2.0 * dot( V, H ) * H - V);
260: 
261:        float ndotl = clamp(dot(N, L),0.0,1.0);
262: 
263:        if (ndotl>0.0) {
264: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_PANORAMA
265:            sum.rgb += texturePanorama(H,source_panorama).rgb *ndotl;
266: #endif
267: 
268: #ifdef USE_SOURCE_DUAL_PARABOLOID_ARRAY
269: 
270:            sum.rgb += textureDualParaboloidArray(H).rgb *ndotl;
271: #endif
272: 
273: #if !defined(USE_SOURCE_DUAL_PARABOLOID_ARRAY) && !defined(USE_SOURCE_PANORAMA)
274:            H.y=-H.y;
275:            sum.rgb += textureLod(source_cube, H, 0.0).rgb *ndotl;
276: #endif
277:            sum.a += ndotl;
278:        }
279:    }
280:    sum /= sum.a;
281: 
282:    frag_color = vec4(sum.rgb, 1.0);
283: 
284: #endif
285: 
286: }
287: 
288: 
**ERROR**: CubemapFilterShaderGLES3: Fragment Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '2863311530u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '3435973836u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '4042322160u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '4278255360u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:168:_display_error_with_code() - CubemapFilterShaderGLES3: Fragment Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '2863311530u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '3435973836u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '4042322160u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '4278255360u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**: CubemapFilterShaderGLES3: Fragment Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '2863311530u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '3435973836u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '4042322160u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '4278255360u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:441:get_current_version() - CubemapFilterShaderGLES3: Fragment Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '2863311530u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:24: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '3435973836u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:25: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '4042322160u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:26: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '4278255360u' : integer overflow 
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:27: '&' :  wrong operand types  no operation '&' exists that takes a left-hand operand of type 'in highp uint' and a right operand of type 'const mediump int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**: Method/Function Failed, returning: 0L
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:449:get_current_version() - Method/Function Failed, returning: 0L
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: false
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:123:bind() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: false
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
1: #version 300 es
2: #define USE_TEXTURE_RECT
3: #define USE_RGBA_SHADOWS
4: precision highp float;
5: precision highp int;
6: precision highp sampler2D;
7: precision highp samplerCube;
8: precision highp sampler2DArray;
9: 
10: 
11: layout(location=0) in highp vec2 vertex;
12: layout(location=3) in vec4 color_attrib;
13: 
14: #ifdef USE_TEXTURE_RECT
15: 
16: uniform vec4 dst_rect;
17: uniform vec4 src_rect;
18: 
19: #else
20: 
21: #ifdef USE_INSTANCING
22: 
23: layout(location=8) in highp vec4 instance_xform0;
24: layout(location=9) in highp vec4 instance_xform1;
25: layout(location=10) in highp vec4 instance_xform2;
26: layout(location=11) in lowp vec4 instance_color;
27: 
28: #ifdef USE_INSTANCE_CUSTOM
29: layout(location=12) in highp vec4 instance_custom_data;
30: #endif
31: 
32: #endif
33: 
34: layout(location=4) in highp vec2 uv_attrib;
35: 
36: //skeletn
37: #endif
38: 
39: uniform highp vec2 color_texpixel_size;
40: 
41: 
42: layout(std140) uniform CanvasItemData { //ubo:0
43: 
44:     highp mat4 projection_matrix;
45:     highp float time;
46: };
47: 
48: uniform highp mat4 modelview_matrix;
49: uniform highp mat4 extra_matrix;
50: 
51: 
52: out highp vec2 uv_interp;
53: out mediump vec4 color_interp;
54: 
55: #ifdef USE_NINEPATCH
56: 
57: out highp vec2 pixel_size_interp;
58: #endif
59: 
60: 
61: #ifdef USE_LIGHTING
62: 
63: layout(std140) uniform LightData { //ubo:1
64: 
65:     //light matrices
66:     highp mat4 light_matrix;
67:     highp mat4 light_local_matrix;
68:     highp mat4 shadow_matrix;
69:     highp vec4 light_color;
70:     highp vec4 light_shadow_color;
71:     highp vec2 light_pos;
72:     highp float shadowpixel_size;
73:     highp float shadow_gradient;
74:     highp float light_height;
75:     highp float light_outside_alpha;
76:     highp float shadow_distance_mult;
77: };
78: 
79: 
80: out vec4 light_uv_interp;
81: 
82: 
83: out vec4 local_rot;
84: 
85: 
86: #ifdef USE_SHADOWS
87: out highp vec2 pos;
88: #endif
89: 
90: const bool at_light_pass = true;
91: #else
92: const bool at_light_pass = false;
93: #endif
94: 
95: #ifdef USE_PARTICLES
96: uniform int h_frames;
97: uniform int v_frames;
98: #endif
99: 
100: 
101: #if defined(USE_MATERIAL)
102: 
103: layout(std140) uniform UniformData { //ubo:2
104: 
105: 
106: };
107: 
108: #endif
109: 
110: 
111: void main() {
112: 
113:    vec4 color = color_attrib;
114: 
115: #ifdef USE_INSTANCING
116:    mat4 extra_matrix2 = extra_matrix * transpose(mat4(instance_xform0,instance_xform1,instance_xform2,vec4(0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0)));
117:    color*=instance_color;
118:    vec4 instance_custom = instance_custom_data;
119: 
120: #else
121:    mat4 extra_matrix2 = extra_matrix;
122:    vec4 instance_custom = vec4(0.0);
123: #endif
124: 
125: #ifdef USE_TEXTURE_RECT
126: 
127:    if (dst_rect.z < 0.0) { // Transpose is encoded as negative dst_rect.z
128:        uv_interp = src_rect.xy + abs(src_rect.zw) * vertex.yx;
129:    } else {
130:        uv_interp = src_rect.xy + abs(src_rect.zw) * vertex;
131:    }
132:    highp vec4 outvec = vec4(dst_rect.xy + abs(dst_rect.zw) * mix(vertex,vec2(1.0,1.0)-vertex,lessThan(src_rect.zw,vec2(0.0,0.0))),0.0,1.0);
133: 
134: #else
135:    uv_interp = uv_attrib;
136:    highp vec4 outvec = vec4(vertex,0.0,1.0);
137: #endif
138: 
139: 
140: #ifdef USE_PARTICLES
141:    //scale by texture size
142:    outvec.xy/=color_texpixel_size;
143: 
144:    //compute h and v frames and adjust UV interp for animation
145:    int total_frames = h_frames * v_frames;
146:    int frame = min(int(float(total_frames) *instance_custom.z),total_frames-1);
147:    float frame_w = 1.0/float(h_frames);
148:    float frame_h = 1.0/float(v_frames);
149:    uv_interp.x = uv_interp.x * frame_w + frame_w * float(frame % h_frames);
150:    uv_interp.y = uv_interp.y * frame_h + frame_h * float(frame / h_frames);
151: 
152: #endif
153: 
154: #define extra_matrix extra_matrix2
155: 
156: {
157: 
158: 
159: }
160: 
161: 
162: #ifdef USE_NINEPATCH
163: 
164:    pixel_size_interp=abs(dst_rect.zw) * vertex;
165: #endif
166: 
167: #if !defined(SKIP_TRANSFORM_USED)
168:    outvec = extra_matrix * outvec;
169:    outvec = modelview_matrix * outvec;
170: #endif
171: 
172: #undef extra_matrix
173: 
174:    color_interp = color;
175: 
176: #ifdef USE_PIXEL_SNAP
177: 
178:    outvec.xy=floor(outvec+0.5).xy;
179: #endif
180: 
181: 
182:    gl_Position = projection_matrix * outvec;
183: 
184: #ifdef USE_LIGHTING
185: 
186:    light_uv_interp.xy = (light_matrix * outvec).xy;
187:    light_uv_interp.zw =(light_local_matrix * outvec).xy;
188: #ifdef USE_SHADOWS
189:    pos=outvec.xy;
190: #endif
191: 
192: 
193:    local_rot.xy=normalize( (modelview_matrix * ( extra_matrix * vec4(1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0) )).xy  );
194:    local_rot.zw=normalize( (modelview_matrix * ( extra_matrix * vec4(0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0) )).xy  );
195: #ifdef USE_TEXTURE_RECT
196:    local_rot.xy*=sign(src_rect.z);
197:    local_rot.zw*=sign(src_rect.w);
198: #endif
199: 
200: 
201: 
202: #endif
203: 
204: }
205: 
206: 
**ERROR**: CanvasShaderGLES3: Vertex Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:29: 'mix' : no matching overloaded function found 
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:168:_display_error_with_code() - CanvasShaderGLES3: Vertex Program Compilation Failed:
**ERROR**: ERROR: 0:29: 'mix' : no matching overloaded function found 
**ERROR**: 
**ERROR**: Method/Function Failed, returning: 0L
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:354:get_current_version() - Method/Function Failed, returning: 0L
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: false
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.cpp:123:bind() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: false
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**: Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
**ERROR**:    At: drivers/gles3/shader_gles3.h:377:_get_uniform() - Condition ' !version ' is true. returned: -1
```

Comment: Looks like you're having problems with fragment shaders. You can see if it works outside godot (using ShaderToy, for example).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the OpenGL ES renderer from GLES3 to GLSE2
Here is how to do it:
[To change the GLES2 inside Godot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMGe3.png)

I hope it fixes your problem

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).